# Google play android icon size violation

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-drawable

My application is disabled by google play store due to the following issue

> application has been removed from Google Play because it violates the device and
>   network abuse policy. The large dimensions of your app's launcher icon
>   negatively impacts the performance of some user devices.

But I provided different icons for different resolutions in drawable folders. I need to get a better solution for this issue. Thanks

Comment: Looks strange. Did you use android studio to generate icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for it. There were some logo icons which exceeds 2048x2048 in drawable-xxhdpi and drawable-xxxhdpi.

> Make changes to your app icon to bring your app into compliance. Your
>   app’s launcher icon size must not exceed 2048x2048.

This also come up with the review feedback.

Therefore I copied drawable-xhdpi which doesn't exceed 2048x2048 logo for other problematic drawable folders.

Answer (score 1):

Though this seems to be quite unlikely - I mean - icon size being too large is quite unlikely.

You could use Android studio to generate your launcher icon. If you are using API 19 or higher latest version of Android studio should generate webP images.

In case this doesn't reduce the size sufficiently, you need to use some image editor to compress or reduce your icon size. Possible solutions - if you are using windows paint is an option if you are not using transparency, also there are plenty of inline image editing tools available.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked for you so that others can also benefit

Comment: I upvoted your solution. But this is not an exact solution what I want. I updated answer for this question. Thanks

Comment: Great job +++++

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make adaptive icons with android Image Asset Studio provide by Android Studio itself. so the icon size of xxxhdpi launcher must not be greater than 512*512.

[Follow the link to generate adaptive icons.](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio)